# What happens if an LM2576 voltage regulator fails?

Tags: voltage-regulator, buck

I made a circuit with the [LM2576](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2576.pdf) to convert 12V from my car, to 5V to charge my mobile phone.

- But what will happen if LM2576 stops working?
- Is that possible that it could damage my mobile phone?

My circuit is the same as the circuit in the datasheet of LM2576. 
Components are:

- 100uF input capacitor
- 1000uF output capacitor
- 100uH inductor
- Schottky diode

The same as datasheet.

[image: LM2576 prototype board]

Comment: Your input cap is not good enough .Do something about it to reduce the chance of EMC issues and to get reliability better than the cheap china stuff that is out there .

Comment: What do you recommend to add this circuit? @Autistic

Comment: You could use 1000 microfarad on the input like your output and then it should last a very long time .

Comment: IF you bend the IC and the screw scrapes the magnet wire , what happens? poof

Answer (score 2):

> But what will happen if LM2576 stops working?

Many results are *possible*; components can fail in different ways.

> Is that possible that it could damage my mobile phone?

Yes, that is *possible*.

Also note that your prototype shown in your photo does *not* meet the recommendations shown in the LM2576 datasheet regarding the component layout. Therefore it might behave badly, have poor output regulation, cause EMI-related problems for nearby devices, oscillate until the LM2576 is damaged, or other behaviours. Personally, I would not plug my mobile phone into that board :-(

Switching regulator design is harder than just using the correct components, because component and wiring (e.g. PCB) layout is also critical, as explained in the datasheet. Perhaps you should considering buying a suitable pre-built regulator from a reputable supplier?

Comment: Failure is [[NOT]] an option!. ie yes it can happen, it must not. Consider somewhat rugged zener diode on output and a sensibly low current input fuse. 5V6 MAY be marginal, 6V3 - less current at 5V but less protection. Very small series R if input wiring heavy to  limit fuse current somewhat. Gives zener a chance to bite. Low enough to still allow fuse to blow.

Comment: My mobiles draw about 1.5A. Could a Zener diode supply that? or I have to use transistor too? @RussellMcMahon

Comment: @sajjad The zener is not to supply current but to provide a path to earth to clamp the voltage and dissipate power if the smps IC goes short circuit and 'tries' to apply higher voltage than 5V to the phone. You can get zeners in a range of wattages - 1W 3W 5W 10W ... . In this case the zener has to dissipate power only long enough for the fuse to blow. A zener plus transistor clamp could be used but is slightly more complex than just using a high wattage zener. Too low a wattage zener may result in it being 'blown' if 12V is applied and the protection failing.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon where I have to add the fuse a 12V at input of circuit or a 5V at output?
You mean I have to add a Zener diode parallel with output voltage? do I have add a series resistor with Zener diode to limit its current? 
schematic of the circuit after adding Zener diode:
[Zener diode](http://imgur.com/a/8qUv3)

Comment: @sajjad Zener location correct. As above " ...Very small series R if input wiring heavy to limit fuse current somewhat." IF input is eg car battery and can source many 10's of amp a zener may die before the fuse blows. Series resistor should limit current to well over fuse limit (so it blows) but so zener survives long enough. Zener spec sheet advises 1 time surge allowed and good fuse makers spec current against time. Any series resistor also must survive longer than the fuse does. (Designing such apparently simple things can be more complex than it looks). Fuse either side of regulator OK.